# React useState giving previous state value always

Tags: reactjs, relaymodern

I am new to React Hooks and trying to build functional component. In my component i have two calendar which user can select date range. As user select date, i need to update my query. I try using useState but my state value is always stole and always give me previous value of calendar. I tried useRef without any success.

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect, useRef} from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { createRefetchContainer, graphql } from "react-relay";
import MaterialTable, {MTableToolbar} from 'material-table';
import moment from 'moment';
import {
  Radio,
  RadioGroup,
  FormControlLabel } from '@material-ui/core';

 import MomentUtils from '@date-io/moment';
 import { DatePicker,MuiPickersUtilsProvider } from '@material-ui/pickers';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    display: 'flex',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
  control: {
    padding: theme.spacing(2),
  },
  group: {
    margin: theme.spacing(0, 1),
  },
}));

let liveDate = (numberofDays) => {
 return {
    Logical_Operator: "AND",
    Rules: [
      {Field:"startdate", Value: moment().format("MM/DD/YYYY"),
       Comparison_Operator: "GREATER_THAN_EQUAL", Type: "String"},
      {Field:"startdate", Value:moment().add(numberofDays,'days').format("MM/DD/YYYY"),   Comparison_Operator:"LESS_THAN_EQUAL", Type: "String"},
      {Field:"active", Value:"True",Comparison_Operator: "EQUAL", Type: "Boolean"}
    ]
  }
}

const UpcomingCampaigns = (props) => {
  const [sort] = useState({field: "startdate", direction:"Asc"});
  const [value, setValue] = useState("0");
  const [startDate, setstartDate] = useState(moment().format("MM/DD/YYYY"));
  const [endDate, setendDate] = useState(moment().format("MM/DD/YYYY"));

  //https://overreacted.io/how-are-function-components-different-from-classes/
  const lateststartDate = useRef(startDate);
  const latestendDate = useRef(endDate);

  function handleChange(event) {

    setValue(event.target.value);
    props.relay.refetch({
      dynamic_query: liveDate(event.target.value),
      sort}, null,
      () => {console.log('Refetch done')},
      {force:true});
  }

  useEffect( () => {
    lateststartDate.current = startDate;
    latestendDate.current = endDate;
    props.relay.refetch({
      dynamic_query: liveDate(0),
      sort});
  }, []);

  let ReRunQuery = () => {
    console.log('StartDate is ', moment(startDate).format("MM/DD/YYYY"))
    console.log('EndDate is ', moment(endDate).format("MM/DD/YYYY"))
    let newQuery = {
       Logical_Operator: "AND",
       Rules: [
         {Field:"startdate", Value: startDate,
          Comparison_Operator: "GREATER_THAN_EQUAL", Type: "String"},
         {Field:"enddate", Value:endDate, Comparison_Operator:"LESS_THAN_EQUAL", Type: "String"},
         {Field:"active", Value:"True",Comparison_Operator: "EQUAL", Type: "Boolean"}
       ]
     };

     console.log('New Query is ', newQuery)
     props.relay.refetch({
      dynamic_query: newQuery,
      sort}, null,
      () => {console.log('Refetch done')},
      {force:true});

   }

  const handleStartDateChange = (date) => {
    setstartDate(moment(date).format("MM/DD/YYYY"));
    console.log('StartDate is ', {startDate})
    console.log('latest StartDate is ', moment(lateststartDate.current).format("MM/DD/YYYY"))
    //ReRunQuery();
  }
  const handleEndDateChange = (date) => {
    setendDate(moment(date).format("MM/DD/YYYY"));
    console.log('Again EndDate is ', moment(latestendDate.current).format("MM/DD/YYYY"))
    //ReRunQuery();
  }

  const buildData = () => {
    let tabledata = [];

    {props.Viewer &&
      props.Viewer.CampaignGrids &&
      props.Viewer.CampaignGrids.edges.length &&
      props.Viewer.CampaignGrids.edges.map(({ node }) => {
        const flattenCampaign = ({Campaign_TypeFull,...rest}) => Object.assign({}, rest, Campaign_TypeFull);
        tabledata.push(flattenCampaign(node))
      })
    }
    return tabledata;
  }

  const renderTable = () => {
    let campaignData = buildData();
    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
      <div>

        <MaterialTable
          columns={[
            { title: 'Name', field: 'Name'},
            { title: 'Campaign Type', field: 'text'},
            { title: 'Start Date', field: 'Start_Date'},
            { title: 'End Date', field: 'End_Date'},
          ]}
          data={campaignData}
          title="Upcoming Active Campaigns"
          options={
              { paging:false,
                search: false,
                //totalCount: props.Viewer.Campaigns.totalCount,
                backgroundColor: '#EEE',
                headerStyle: { backgroundColor: '#039be5', color: '#FFF', 'fontWeight': 'bold', 'fontSize' : '14px'},
                rowStyle: {backgroundColor: '#EEE'},
                doubleHorizontalScroll: true,
                maxBodyHeight:225,
                paginationType: 'normal',
                emptyRowsWhenPaging: false,
              }}
          components={{
            Toolbar: props => (
              <div>
                  <MTableToolbar {...props} />
                  <RadioGroup
                      aria-label="Gender"
                      name="gender1"
                      className={classes.group}
                      value={value}
                      row={true}
                      onChange={handleChange}
                    >
                    <FormControlLabel value="0" control={<Radio />} label="Today" />
                    {/* <FormControlLabel value="3" control={<Radio />} label="Next 3 days" />
                    <FormControlLabel value="7" control={<Radio />} label="Next 7 days" /> */}
                    <DatePicker value={startDate} label="Start Date" onChange={date => handleStartDateChange(date)} autoOk="true" format="MM/DD/YYYY" variant="inline"
                    inputVariant="outlined" />
                    <DatePicker value={endDate} label="End Date" onChange={ date => handleEndDateChange(date)} autoOk="true" format="MM/DD/YYYY" variant="inline"
                    inputVariant="outlined" />

                    </RadioGroup>
              </div>
            )
          }}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }

  return (
    <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={MomentUtils}>
      {renderTable()}
    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
  )
}

export default createRefetchContainer(
  UpcomingCampaigns,
  {
    Viewer: graphql`
    fragment UpcomingCampaigns_Viewer on Viewer  @argumentDefinitions(
      sort: {type: "Sort", defaultValue:{field: "startdate", direction:"Asc"}}
      dynamic_query: {
        type: "QueryBuilder",
        defaultValue: {
          Logical_Operator:AND,
          Rules: [
            {Field:"startdate", Value: "2019-04-28 23:59:59.000Z",Comparison_Operator:GREATER_THAN_EQUAL, Type: "String"},
            {Field:"startdate", Value:"2019-04-28 23:59:59.000Z",Comparison_Operator:LESS_THAN_EQUAL, Type: "String"},
            {Field:"active", Value:"True",Comparison_Operator:EQUAL, Type: "Boolean"}
          ]
        }
      }
      ) {
      CampaignGrids(sort: $sort, dynamic_query:$dynamic_query ) {
        totalCount
        edges {
          node {
            id
            Name
            Campaign_Type
            Start_Date
            End_Date
            Campaign_TypeFull {
              text
              value
            }

          }
        }
      }
    }
  `
},
graphql`
  query UpcomingCampaignsRefetchQuery(
    $dynamic_query: QueryBuilder!
    $sort: Sort
  ) {
    Viewer {
      ...UpcomingCampaigns_Viewer
      @arguments(
        dynamic_query: $dynamic_query
        sort: $sort
      )
    }
  }
`
);
```

I am not sure what am i missing here

Answer (score 3):

useState is asynchronous so sometimes the value wont immediately be effect - You need to implement useEffect in order for it to run properly

```
useEffect(() => {
 // do something when startDate updates
 }, [startDate]);
```

Comment: I already have useEffect and i added [startDate] but no success

Answer (score -1):

If your state is changing frequently, converting to class component with state solves the problem for us.

Comment: While trying to be helpful I know, effectively stating 'give up and use the old format' isn't especially useful here! :)